# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`role_id`, `name`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, lino, lino, lino@gmail.com, $2y$10$8i2ucs2nRv.ggnRHNmiK/.QPNJ4uRNwjRZCg5D6ILUMFvyr5.qyXW, 2020-01-03 21:36:49, 2020-01-03 21:36:49))
```

Why this error is showing in live server but no errors in localhost?

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'role_id' => 2,
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => str_slug($data['username']),
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: "Why this error is showing in live server but no errors in localhost?" -- Probably because your database is configured differently on localhost than on the server.

Comment: I imported the exact database from the localhost. Besides the registration, everything is working fine

Comment: You should verify your database structure.- whether `users` table `id` column is set as autoincromenting

Answer (score 0):

Your User Table id is not Auto increment . Make it Auto increment.